# How to sort twice with two columns in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4,
How to sort twice with two columns?

For example:

`ArticleController.php`

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Auth::user()->articles->sortByDesc('updated_at')->sortByDesc('status');
    return view('index',  compact('articles'));
}
```

I use `sortByDesc()` twice,but the result does not follow the rules,what should I do?

**update:**
`User.php`

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

Comment: There's a spelling error there: `public function artilces()` vs `articles`

Comment: @Tim Lewis  thanks,it's ok.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't sort on collection but you should get sorted results from database like this:

```
$articles = Auth::user()->articles()
              ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
              ->orderBy('status','DESC')
              ->get();
```

To explain a bit more - in your code you got all results from database (in random order) and then tried to sort all the results.

In code I presented you sort results in database so you can easily sort on mutliple columns.

Notice difference in my code - instead of `->articles` I used `->articles()` and added `->get()` at the end to get results.

Comment: but there is an error,"Method orderBy does not exist."

Comment: @zwl1619 So what exactly are articles? I thought it's relationship. Can you share the definition?

Comment: yes, it's relationship, `User` and `Article` have a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @zwl1619 So it should work without a problem assuming you have `articles` relationship and not `artilces` as you wrote in your question and you added `()` after articles in the code I showed, so you used exact code I wrote in here. Because there is a big difference if you use `articles()` and `articles` in here